# .htaccess - multiple page by page redirects + www & https rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Been struggling and playing with this and can't get it working in Apache.

I'm not well versed in the syntax and was rather trying to build something based on existing questions on here.

Trying to force everything to HTTPS and www, and also add over 200 individual page redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect URLs.
Redirect 301 /PAGE1 /PAGE2
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in thw www part remove the https condition and redirect with https and www anyway

in the https part remove the www condition

after those 2 ... continue with all your paged redirecting

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain with HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect URLs.
Redirect 301 /PAGE1 /PAGE2
```